# Should be an array, but typeof says it's an object, Chrome console displays it as an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have this problem which may sounds stupid but I don't really understand the whys.
I declare it as a variable: `let [ randomQuoterState, setrandomQuoterState ] = useState([]);` Then pass it into a component inside the return: `<UserOutput set={setrandomQuoterState} current={randomQuoterState} number={1}/>`
The following code is inside the component:

```
            let toSet = [];
            toSet[props.number] = quoteArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteArray.length)];
            let quote = props.current;
            if (quote[props.number]){
                delete quote[props.number];
                console.log("deleted")
            }else {
                console.log("this does not exist");
            }
            console.log(typeof(toSet[props.number]));
            console.log(toSet[props.number].lenght)
            console.log(toSet[props.number]);
            quote[props.number] = toSet[props.number][Math.floor(Math.random() * toSet[props.number].lenght)];
            props.set(quote);
```

The Consol displays it as an array, but the typeof function says its an object, and it doesn't have a length property.

[image]

I would appreciate any help or explanation, I thought about it a lot, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: That's what `typeof` does for arrays.

Comment: Because `lenght` isn't how you spell that.

Comment: `delete quote[props.number];` you sure you want to mutate state?

Comment: @AttilaBerczik because there is a typo! (`lenght` instead of `length`.) I don't edit the question because then the output image wouldn't correspond to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are objects in Javascript. In fact, there is no `array` type.

To see if it is an array, you should try `console.log((toSet[props.number]).constructor.name)` and do your checks against `toSet[props.number] instanceof Array`.

Do *not* use `(toSet[props.number]).constructor.name == 'Array'` in your comparisons, because you could have something that has inherited from Array but whose constructor name is different.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript both `object` and `array` are of type `Object`.

In case you want to determine exact type, you can use constructor property.

```
const data = {};
data.contructor.name === 'Object'; // Returns True

const data = [];
data.contructor.name === 'Object'; // Returns True
data.contructor.name === 'Object'; // Returns False
```

Above can used to determine `String`, `Date` etc as well.

Alternatively you can use libraries like lodash which has function for these things.
However that is overkill I guess.

Hope it helps.